# Missing CSS Elements from Linked Stylesheet

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple table which I am trying to right-align the inputs in. The issue I am having is getting the input property to apply the right-align attribute I've included in the CSS file. When I view the CSS file in the Chrome data inspector it shows only the .table-responsive attribute and not the input or table attributes. If I manually type the attributes in the chrome inspector they apply so I do not think it is my structure.

I'm wondering why only the .table-responsive attribute is showing and not the others? I've read it may be a formatting error, but I am having trouble finding out where my formatting might be going wrong.

I am using bootstrap and a bootstrap theme, just in case that might matter.

**CSS**

```
table {
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

input {
    text-align: right;
}

.table-responsive {
    display: contents;
}
```

**Chrome Inspector CSS**

```
.table-responsive {
    display: contents;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/Journalize.css" />

        <title>Journalize</title>
    </head>

</html>
    <body>
        <br/>
        <h2>Journalize</h2>
        <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <table border="1" class="table-responsive table-bordered table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Transaction ID</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                                <th>Date</th>
                                <th>Type</th>
                                <th>Account</th>
                                <th>Debit</th>
                                <th>Credit</th>
                                <th>User</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <?php retrieveJournal(); ?>
```

PHP

```
function retrieveJournal() {
        ...
            echo '<tr align="center">';
                echo '<td> <span>' .$row['transaction_id']. '</span> </td>';
                echo '<td> 
                        <select name="status[]">
                            <option '.$approvedStatus.'>Approved</option>
                            <option '.$pendingStatus.'>Pending</option>
                            <option '.$rejectedStatus.'>Rejected</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>';
                echo '<td> <input name="transactiondate[]" readonly value="' .$row['transaction_date']. '"> </td>';
                echo '<td> 
                        <select name="transactiontype[]">
                            <option '.$normalType.'>Normal</option>
                            <option '.$adjustingType.'>Adjusting</option>
                            <option '.$closingType.'>Closing</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>';
                echo '<td>
                        <input name="transactionaccount[]" readonly value="' .$accountRow['account_name']. '">
                        <br/>
                        <span>Description: </span><input name="description[]" value ="' .$row['description']. '">
                      </td>';
                echo '<td> <input name="debitAmount[]" readonly value="' .$row['debit_amount']. '"> </td>';
                echo '<td> <input name="creditAmount[]" readonly value="' .$row['credit_amount']. '"> </td>';
                echo '<td> <input name="user_id[]" readonly value="' . $usernameRow['username'] . '"> </td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the elements are not showing in the developer options, in sources is because your browser has cached the old version of the CSS file.

You can prevent the browser from loading cached files by adding a random version number on the end, for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/Journalize.css?v=<?= date("Ymd") . time(); ?>" />
```

Giving you an output of something that'll always be a new version so the browser cannot load old cached versions.

```
style/Journalize.css?v=201810271540661219
```

Comment: Fantastic. I should have tested it in incognito as that confirmed what you said right away. Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: Would you know why going in the options and clearing the website manually through the "Cookies" page would not solve this issue? I gave that a try before I posted the question, but it seems like that didn't solve the caching issue.

Comment: Browsers do not cache using cookies, you needed to go to `Options > Advanced > Clear Browsing data > Cached images and files > Clear data`. Hope this helped.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks again! :)